# How to connect to a Rackspace server via SSL

Tags: php, ssl

I am attempting to connect to a server with given credentials similar to the mock-ups ones I pasted below; however it was noted that I must connect via SSL. Duh, Duh, Duh.

I haven't connected to a server via SSL before;

```
 Service     URL/IP  Username    Password                           
 Rackspace Server (cool)     55.55.555.555   root    R33399999                          
 Rackspace Server (valet) Database server    55.55.555.555   root    R33399999                          
 URL     Server  Path    DB Username     DB Password     DB Host     DB Table Name   Admin URL   Username    Password
 http://test.com.test.verycool.com/  cool    /var/www/wp/test.com    wp_cool
```

I tried FileZilla, but it appears there is not toggle to connect via SSL with them; then I tried Cyber Duck, I tried using the (WebDAV SSL connection option) - I get listing directory failed error; then I tried using the FTP-SSL option, and just get a wheel > Connection Failed.

Rackspace Server

Cheers for any pointers

Comment: What programming language are you trying to use? If you're not writing a program, this is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! It's a PHP environment

Comment: What do you mean by "connect via SSL"? SSL is an encryption method that's used around some other application protocol, e.g. HTTPS is HTTP+SSL, FTPS is FTP+SSL, etc.

Comment: This does not look to be a question of debugging. Rather, "code for me"

Comment: reads like your having issues with an ftp client trying to connect to  your host ?

Comment: Also, just noticed. It seems you have left sensitive data in your questions body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little confusing as it looks like you are trying to access the wordpress admin site on the server as opposed to an FTP site and Wordpress is requiring SSL access, which means the URL needs to start with "https" instead of "http".  So instead of "http://test.com.test.verycool.com/" the url would be "https://test.com.test.verycool.com/" in your browser.

If it really is FTP credentials, the settings in Filezilla for FTPS is to use "FTP" in the Protocol select box and either explicit or implicit "FTP over TLS" in the encryption drop down.  Yes, Filezilla makes it confusing but what are you going to do?  I reall do think though that rackspace gives you access through a browser based file manager interface.  Hope that gets you going:)